# Drive API OAuth2 with HTTPS Only

Tags: http, https, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I have been studying the DriveAPI for a while now and can't seem to find a simple way to get it to work just for MY needs only...

I would like to use the DriveAPI only with just the REST API (HTTPS).

There are many things like token, clientid, apikey, secrets, etc.

All I need, is to search MY OWN GDrive files (FULLTEXT CONTAINS) and get a result from the API but I can't get it to work.

Please remember, this is for my own needs only and I would like to bypass the verification (login) window and get some kind of token, that lasts forever, so I can implement this in my own tool.

So, how can I authenticate and use the DriveAPI with just plain HTTPS?

My efforts so far:

I have already made a client ID and a client KEY for a sample project in the dashboard. I have also an Google Drive API KEY. From this point, I don't really know where and what to send.

Comment: There is no "bypass" for the OAuth 2.0 authentication (that's why there is authentication enforced in the first place). Have you done any coding for this that you can share? For most REST API's OAuth 2.0 authentication is required. Your application must be able to request the token and use it to make the requests.

Comment: @FilipedosSantos I have edited my question

Comment: Which programming language is being used? Have you done any coding so far?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, there is no "bypass" for the OAuth 2.0 authentication (that's why there is authentication enforced in the first place). Have you done any coding for this that you can share? For most REST API's OAuth 2.0 authentication is required. Your application must be able to request the token and use it to make the requests.

Google API's use Google Identity service to provide the tokens. In the following document there are many examples of how this implementation should be done in different programming languages:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer